# Unwanted text showing up in label in C# app

Tags: c#, text, binary, label

I'm having a peculiar problem with a program in C#:

First I write some text from a textbox to a binary file using this code:

```
            bw.Write(CorrectAnswerResponse.ToString());
```

Then I read that text from the binary file to a label using this code:

```
             CorrectAnswerResponse = br.ReadString();
```

The problem occurs when the destination label shows the following text:

"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Correct! Ringo Starr's birth name is Richard Starkey."

All I should see is this:

"Correct! Ringo Starr's birth name is Richard Starkey."

All other data from the binary file is being written, read and displayed correctly. Where is "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: " coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the text like this?

```
CorrectAnswerResponse.Text = br.ReadString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the text itself, not the class name.

```
bw.Write(CorrectAnswerResponse.Text);
```

And read the string into the label:

```
CorrectAnswerResponse.Text = br.ReadString();
```